# Check user access to sites and lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, permissions, rest, navigation

There is SharePoint's site with custom welcome page (which is a HTML page) designed to have custom navigation menu. Navigation urls are like this:

```
https://spsite1
https://spsite2
http://google.com (any other resource outside of sharepoint)
https://spsite1/sites/publishing
https://spsite1/sites/publishing/mylibrary1
```

I need to check if user has access to those different sites and if not to hide related nodes from navigation menu. What's the simplest solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Following function will help you to find the permission level for user. here permission level checked is"viewListItems" , you can find rest of the permissionkind from here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556747(v=office.14).aspx

```
function CheckPermission(){
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.Runtime.js', 'SP.ClientContext',
    function() {
      SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext',
      function() {
        var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        clientContext.load(web, 'Title', 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onError);
      });
  });
}
function onSuccess(){
  alert('Title: ' + web.get_title());
  var permissions = SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb && SP.PermissionKind.viewListItems;
  if(web.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(permissions)){
    alert('user has the required permissions');
  }
}
function onError(sender, args) {
  alert(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```